# Поиск в массиве подстроки и возврат ключа по которому находиться значение

Tags: php

Реализовываю корзину пользователя, в БД хранятся данные вида `{{id_0001}/(92[1])/}*`, далее с помощью функции explode создаю массив в данном случае получаю массив вида

```php
Array
(
    [0] => {{id_0001}
    [1] => (92[1])
    [2] => }*
)
```

В данном массиве нужно найти позицию числа 92, проблема в том что число 92 (или какое либо другое) будет известно заранее, но НЕизвестным будет число в квадратных скобках [1] и из за этого я не могу воспользоваться такой замечательной функцией как array_search(), эта функция идеальна но подстроки в массиве он не ищет, как решить эту проблему? Прошу показать на живом примере как будет выглядеть код решающий эту проблему, спасибо

Comment: в каком массиве вы хотите искать - вот в этом из 3 элементов?

Comment: да в этом, 3 элемента в нём пока, далее он станет больше и возможно на много

Comment: и тогда все равно это будет линейный массив или двухуровневый по три элемента?

Comment: да, обший вид массива не измениться, одномерный массив

Comment: т.е вы хотите найти позицию в массиве, а не сам элемент?

Comment: вот именно, мне нужно определить позицию чтобы обратиться к элементу массива по индексу и изменить его или вовсе удалить

Comment: написал в ответе для читаемости

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$num = 92;

foreach ($arr as $k=>$v) { 
   if (0 === strpos($v, "({$num}[")) {
       // $k - искомый индекс
       break; 
   }
}
```

Comment: Я так понимаю при нахождении соответствия сработает break из за чего цикл остановиться, и мне остановиться всего лишь отловить значение в переменной $k, верно?

Comment: лучше перед break сделать обработку. если ничего не найдется $k - будет последним индексом в массиве, а это неправильно. А сам break можно оставить - дальше искать нечего

Comment: Спасибо добрый человек, проверю и отпишусь, $k сравню с общим размером массива и если совпадёт значить в массиве нет искомого элемента

Comment: Я не могу понять зачем в условии if strpos(0 == $v, "({$num}[") вот это 0 == $v?

Comment: это я ошибся когда писал - поправил

Comment: скопируйте код и напишите мне, я удалю ответ

Comment: Не могу понять, только ноль видаёт, чтобы я не делал ответ ноль

Comment: Я немного изменил условие ну и это не помогает if (0 == strpos($v, '(' . $product[1] . '['))

Comment: Вы наверное специально написали такое условие, типа чтобы я сам догадался, долго думал и в итоге заработало, но в условии должен быть не ноль а сам массив if ($v == strpos($v, '(' . $product[1] . '[')), теперь понятно зачем вам удалять ответ, в любом случае спасибо, помогло

Comment: нет! strpos возвращает позицию одной строки в другой  0 - значит в начале строки, а  false - её нет. Чтоб отличить надо использовать строгое сравнение ===.  смотрите ттут http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/20a00374d0f46e419ac69b1be2c56a4eb7c0f5be

Comment: if ($v == strpos($v, '(' . $product[1] . '[')) я установил в место 0 $v и оно заработало, могут быть какие-то проблемы в будущем из за этого?

Comment: я не понимаю, как оно заработало с вашими входными данными. сделайте var_export(ваш массив) и подставьте по ссылке - должно получиться 1. А потом поправьте на ваш код и посмотрите, чт получится

Comment: Оно работает 100%, я кайфую, я специально увеличил количество элементов в массиве и оно всё равно работает без ошибок